# ReflectionProperty constructor

Tags: php, reflection

I'll be grateful (and wiser at the same time ;) ) if anyone can explain me below behavior:

We've got a class.

```
class Test {
    public $id;
    private $name;
    protected $color;
}
```

And we've got ReflectionProperty constructor behavior that I do not fully understand.

Working one first:

```
function check() {
    $class = new Test();
    $ref = new ReflectionObject($class);
    $pros = $ref->getProperties();
    foreach ($pros as $pro) {
        false && $pro = new ReflectionProperty();
        print_r($pro);
    }
}
```

This will give correct output of:

```
ReflectionProperty Object
(
    [name] => id
    [class] => Test
)
ReflectionProperty Object
(
    [name] => name
    [class] => Test
)
ReflectionProperty Object
(
    [name] => color
    [class] => Test
)
```

Now: if I remove "false" from this line:

```
false && $pro = new ReflectionProperty();
```

the output will be:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: ReflectionProperty::__construct() expects exactly 2 parameters, 0 given
```

ReflectionProperty::__construct() takes ($class, $name)

The question therefore is:
*why 'false' even works in the first place*?

Comment: with $a && $b, $b are evaluate only if is true $a condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the ReflectionProperty constructor itself.

```php
false && $pro = new ReflectionProperty();
```

Is something called a short circuit. It means that the code on the right will only execute if it needs to. In this case, because you're doing a && (AND) with the left side being false, the engine knows that the result can NEVER equal true, and so it doesn't need to execute and evaluate the right hand side, which is your ReflectionProperty constructor.

Basically, the false && is stopping your broken code from running, and print_r is then using the existing value of pro from the getProperties results.

Answer (score 2):

`false && $pro = new ReflectionProperty();` evaluates to `false`.

Because first condition is `false`, there's no need to evaluate second `$pro = new ReflectionProperty()` (it's called "short circuit evaluation").

When you remove `false` you have line

```
$pro = new ReflectionProperty();
```

and `ReflectionProperty` constructor **requires two arguments** (and error message tells you about this).

Comment: Both answers explained subject perfectly; hope you don't mind i accept new contributor answer.